# Setting event handlers to DOM objects

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom

I was looking for the most proper way to attach DOM events avoiding browser compatibility issues and found that the [Mozilla developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference/DOM_Events) site states:

> The old way is to just assign it like this:
>
> ```
> document.getElementById('cupcakeButton').onclick = getACupcake;
> ```
>
> As above, the event object is either a global or an argument. This
>   method may have problems and is not the preferred method, but it still
>   works and a lot of people still use it.

What type of problems does this refer to?

Comment: For one, if you try to attach two handlers to the same event on the same element, the second one will replace the first one. The usual expectation is that an event may have many handlers. What happens when you combine the two approaches is also anything but obvious. (I.e. does "assigning" a handler replace the previous "added" ones? Do they all get called? Can you "remove" the assigned handler? I'm sure all of these are specified, but it's better to just stick to one method instead of keeping this in your head.)

Comment: I recommend to read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html. It mentions some problems as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious one is already mentioned, [it would replace a previously assigned handler](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html#link5).

`document.getElementById('id')` should work in all browsers except in really old ones [(`Netscape 4-`, `IE 4-`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Migrate_apps_from_Internet_Explorer_to_Mozilla), there you should use `document.layers['id']` and `document.all[id]` respectively.

`IE 5 up to IE 7` [have one more issue](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements), which is that they will also return elements where `name='id'` instead of only the elements where `id='id'`. That could really stuff you up.

Have a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for a way to attach DOM event handlers avoiding browser compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem I can think of is that it won't allow assigning multiple click handlers, by doing another `.onclick = fn;` you basically unbind the previous handler if it was there.

Even if that magically worked, you would have no way to unregister a specific handler; it's all or nothing.